# \expandafter and counters not playing nicely

Tags: conditionals, counters, expansion

My google-fu has finally failed me...
I'm trying to write a package that will allow you say `\addauthor{name, email}` several times and have the title page properly formatted. Here is a minimal example of my troubles:

```
% FILE: sd.sty
\ProvidesPackage{sd}
\newcounter{authors}
\newcommand{\@authors}{\@empty}
\newcommand{\@authorsnoemail}{\@empty}
\def\addauthor#1{\@addauthor#1\@nil}
\def\@addauthor#1,#2\@nil{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\@authorsnoemail\expandafter{%
    \@authorsnoemail%
    \ifnum\value{authors}>0, \fi%
    #1}
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\@authors\expandafter{\@authors%
    \ifnum\value{authors}=0 \else ; \fi%
    #1 - #2}
  \stepcounter{authors}}
\newcommand{\ane}{\@authorsnoemail}
\newcommand{\auth}{\@authors}
```

and then I try

```
% FILE: main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sd}

\addauthor{1, 1@1}
\addauthor{2, 2@2}
\addauthor{3, 3@3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Expected: & 1, 2, 3 \\
Got: &  \ane\\
Expected: & 1 - 1@1; 2 - 2@2; 3 - 3@3 \\
Got: & \auth \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And the output is

```
Expected: 1, 2, 3
Got:      , 1, 2, 3
Expected: 1 - 1@1; 2 - 2@2; 3 - 3@3
Got:      ; 1 - 1@1; 2 - 2@2; 3 - 3@3
```

My question is "How can I do the counter comparison properly, so that the divider will only be inserted at the second author and above?"

(I included both lists since for some reason removing one makes it work... I suspect I'm doing something wrong with the `\expandafter`s)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

It's probably easier just to deal with the initial case first. I also added an extra `#3` to lose any white space after the comma.

```
% FILE: sd.sty
\ProvidesPackage{sd}
\newcounter{authors}
\let\@authors\@empty
\let\@authorsnoemail\@empty
\def\addauthor#1{\@addauthor#1\@empty\@nil}
\def\@addauthor#1,#2#3\@nil{%
  \ifx\@authors\@empty
     \def\@authorsnoemail{#1}%
     \def\@authors{#1 - #2#3}%
  \else
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\@authorsnoemail\expandafter{%
    \@authorsnoemail, #1}%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\@authors\expandafter{%
    \@authors; #1 - #2#3}%
   \fi
  \stepcounter{authors}}
\newcommand{\ane}{\@authorsnoemail}
\newcommand{\auth}{\@authors}
```

Comment: Perfect -- thanks! @egreg 's answer below explains why this works (problem was with the expansion of `\ifnum`). I still haven't gotten around to LaTeX3, so I like this solution. I'm also getting rid of the counter, since it served no other purpose.

Answer (score 8):

You're not expanding the conditional, which is put inside `\@authors` *as is*: if you do `\makeatletter\show\@authors\makeatother` after the `\addauthor` lines, you get

```
> \@authors=macro:
->\@empty \ifnum \value {authors}=0 \else ; \fi 1 -  1@1\ifnum \value {authors}
=0 \else ; \fi 2 -  2@2\ifnum \value {authors}=0 \else ; \fi 3 -  3@3.
```

which is obviously not what you want.

Here's a way out; just to be more modern than David, I present it in LaTeX3 form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addauthor}{ >{ \SplitArgument { 1 } { , } } m }
 {
  \sd_addauthor:nn #1
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\betteraddauthor}{ m m }
 {
  \sd_addauthor:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ane}{ }
 {
  \seq_use:Nnnn \g_sd_authors_noemail_seq { ,~ } { ,~ } { ,~ }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\auth}{ }
 {
  \seq_use:Nnnn \g_sd_authors_seq { ;~ } { ;~ } { ;~ }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \sd_addauthor:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_sd_authors_seq { #1 ~ - ~ #2 }
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_sd_authors_noemail_seq { #1 }
 }
\seq_new:N \g_sd_authors_seq
\seq_new:N \g_sd_authors_noemail_seq

\ExplSyntaxOff


\addauthor{1, 1@1}
\addauthor{2, 2@2}
\betteraddauthor{3}{3@3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Expected: & 1, 2, 3 \\
Got: &  \ane\\
Expected: & 1 - 1@1; 2 - 2@2; 3 - 3@3 \\
Got: & \auth \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

I don't think that the syntax

```
\addauthor{A. Name, a.name@x.y.z}
```

is so good and I'd prefer

```
\addauthor{A. Name}{a.name@x.y.z}
```

so I've provided the definition of `\betteraddauthor` for the second syntax. Notice that the "internal" macro used is just the same.

Answer (score 3):

The following just uses fewer characters and uses the inserted space without zapping it. This only works because of your suggested output, which requires the space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{authors}
\newcommand{\@authors}{}
\newcommand{\@authorsnoemail}{}
\def\addauthor#1{\@addauthor#1\@nil}
\def\@addauthor#1,#2\@nil{%
  \protected@edef\@authorsnoemail{\@authorsnoemail%
    \ifnum\value{authors}>0, \fi%
    #1}%
  \protected@edef\@authors{\@authors%
    \ifnum\value{authors}>0; \fi%
    #1 -#2}%
  \stepcounter{authors}}
\newcommand{\ane}{\@authorsnoemail}
\newcommand{\auth}{\@authors}
\makeatother
\addauthor{1, 1@1}
\addauthor{2, 2@2}
\addauthor{3, 3@3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Expected: & 1, 2, 3 \\
Got: &  \ane\\
Expected: & 1 - 1@1; 2 - 2@2; 3 - 3@3 \\
Got: & \auth \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\xdef` will cause troubles if an input like `\addauthor{\textbf{1}, 1@1}` is given (I don't know if it is to be expected, though)

Comment: @cgnieder: True.

Comment: Use `\protected@edef`, not `\xdef`: if an author's name has accents you'll be in big troubles. Also, but it is in the original code, why `\@authors` and `\@authorsnoemail` are *not* initialized as empty? The set with the empty set as element is not empty. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: Agreed. I thought it may have been, originally, to test in an `\ifx`. I've removed it.